# Will my Rails app written for 3.2.12 run on a newer version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application (3.2.12) on my laptop with Ruby 2.0.
Will the application run on a new cloud machine with Rails 4.x?

Comment: Yes/no; they are more compatible with each other than rails2 -> rails3 was, but your best resource is the document of changes between the versions...

Answer (score 1):

It may, and it may not.

This depends on app itself, but most probably you should do some migration.
For example rails 4 removed `vendor/plugins`, identity map, all dynamic finders except for `find_by_`, requires all scopes to be callable objects, join table name changed for HABTM and so on

See rails [migration guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using a Ruby/Gem Version management system like RVM - https://rvm.io/

This lets each app specify which version of ruby and which gems (including the specific version for each gem) that app uses, so that when you switch to the app it switches out all the ruby/gem environment that the app expects.

This is pretty much essential if you ever want to have two different rails apps running on the same machine.